# how to duplicate a page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter environment. I have this existing system and I am trying to duplicate one of the admin pages which I thought would work if i just copy, rename and paste.

Example:

(original files and working)

```
application\controllers\admin\calculator.php

application\views\admin\calculator.php
```

it can be access by `domain.org/admin/calculator`

(duplicated)

```
application\controllers\admin\calculatorduplicate.php

application\views\admin\calculatorsduplicate.php
```

tried accessing by `domain.org/admin/calculatorduplicate`
but showing 404

I also added the navigation link inside this file.

```
application\views\admin\header.php
```

What am i missing? I didn't want to change anything inside the file yet, just want to duplicate the page. Please help.

Comment: have you added  **route**  for those duplicate page as you have for original pages?

Comment: application\config\routes.php ? hmm didn't see the original pages inside, so didn't touch those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, first try to understand how CodeIgniter binds its URLs.

In URL:

[http://codeignitersite.com/controller/method/parameter_one/parameter_two/[parameters]....](http://codeignitersite.com/controller/method/parameter_one/parameter_two/%5Bparameters%5D....).

Controller is the Controller class which must have the same name as of its Filename and also as in URL.

Method is the Controller method to be accessed.

In above case, the class name also needs to be changed to:

`class Calculatorduplicate {`

To avoid any 404 error.

Comment: i shall read more on that. thank you for the reference

Comment: it worked! some errors, but no longer 404. i shall experiment more on it. Thank you!